# Why do I have two "Network" sections in System Settings while running Daily?

Tags: settings

After enabling the Daily ppa, a second "Network" section appeared in System Settings. They look different inside.

How can I remove one of these?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You shouldn't remove either of these.**

One is the "daily" plug, and is in the process of being built. As such, it is incomplete, both in that it may not have access to or be able to modify all the settings, and that it might be unstable in some situations.

The other is the "stable" plug, and contains the current, known-to-work code.